# Material UI DataGrid's ColumnMeun is overlapped by Dialog

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

A DataGrid is created within Dialog. But the column menu is overlapped by Dialog.

Please check the following demo
[SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-hertz-6o7ey?file=/src/App.js)

**What I have found and try so far:**

1. Dialog will create a html tag

The z-index:1300 will cover the column menu

```
<div role="presentation" class="MuiDialog-root makeStyles-dialogRoot-41" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1300; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
```

I have try to use classes={{ root: (z-index=0) }} in dialog component. But it still overwrited by 1300.

2.Clicking a column menu will create a tooltip list for selecting sorting action

```
<div role="tooltip" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(217px, 137px, 0px);" x-placement="bottom-end">
```

If I add z-index=1500 in this tag directly in browser(F12). The menu will work fine. But I have no idea how to apply the CSS to this tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `style={{ zIndex: 0 }}` in your `Dialog` component.

```
<Dialog
  open={open}
  onClose={handleClose}
  maxWidth="md"
  fullWidth
  style={{ zIndex: 0 }}
>
```

Check the [snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-water-6zhn8?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Oh.... I was so close to the answers (my solution 1). Since I am using "classes" to apply the style. It will be overwrited but using "style", it will not be overwrited. OMG, I was overthinking about the solution. Thank for your help!!